# Unable to display scatterplot in R shiny

Tags: r

Getting this Error in my code:

> Error in tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", tabPanel("Scatterplot",
>   plotOutput("scatterplot")),  :    argument is missing, with no default

I am creating this linear regression app with R shiny but not able to get the scatterplot on my dashboard, help required!

```
 tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
     tabPanel("Scatterplot", plotOutput("scatterplot")), 
     tabPanel("Distribution",
            fluidRow(
            column(6, plotOutput("distribution1")),
            column(6, plotOutput("distribution2")))
            ),
      tabPanel("Model Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
      )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've just got an extra comma and closing parenthesis at the end that is causing the error:

```
tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
            tabPanel("Scatterplot", plotOutput("scatterplot")), 
            tabPanel("Distribution",
                     fluidRow(
                       column(6, plotOutput("distribution1")),
                       column(6, plotOutput("distribution2")))
            ),
            tabPanel("Model Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary"))
)
```